# create racket accumulator "variable"

Tags: racket

Im really having problems understanding how I can create variable that would act as an  accumulator in racket.  This is definitely a really stupid question....but racket's documentation is pretty difficult for me to read.

I know I will use some kind of define statement or let statement.

I want to be able to pass a number to a variable or function and it adds the current value with the new value keeps the sum...How would I do this....?? Thank you..

```
(define (accumulator newvalue) "current=current+newvalue"
```

something like this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An accumulator is generally just a function parameter. There are a few chapters in How to Design Programs ([online, starting here](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-38.html)) that cover accumulators. Have you read them?

For example, the `reverse` function is implemented using an accumulator that remembers the prefix of the list, reversed:

```
;; reverse : list -> list
(define (reverse elems0)
  ;; reverse/accum : list list -> list
  (define (reverse/accum elems reversed-prefix)
    (cond [(null? elems)
           reversed-prefix]
          [else
           (reverse/accum (cdr elems)
                          (cons (car elems) reversed-prefix))]))
  (reverse/accum elems null))
```

Note that the scope of the accumulator `reversed-prefix` is limited to the function. It is updated by calling the function with a new value for that parameter. Different calls to `reverse` have different accumulators, and `reverse` remembers nothing from one call to the next.

Perhaps you mean *state variable* instead. In that case, you `define` it (or bind it with `let` or `lambda`) at the appropriate scope and update it using `set!`. Here's a global state variable:

```
;; total : number
(define total 0)

;; add-to-total! : number -> number
(define (add-to-total! n)
  (set! total (+ total n))
  total)

(add-to-total! 5) ;; => 5
(add-to-total! 31) ;; => 36
```

Here's a variation that creates local state variables, so you can have multiple counters:

```
;; make-counter : -> number -> number
(define (make-counter)
  (let ([total 0])
    (lambda (n)
      (set! total (+ total n))
      total)))

(define counterA (make-counter))
(define counterB (make-counter))

(counterA 5) ;; => 5
(counterB 10) ;; => 10
(counterA 15) ;; => 20
(counterB 20) ;; => 30
```

But don't call state variables accumulators; it will confuse people.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
(define (accumulator current newvalue)
  (let ((current (+ current newvalue)))
    ...)
```

Comment: No.  I want to be able to add more and more values to it.....I should be able to call accumulator 3 times and add 3 each time.....and each time it displays the previous added with 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can [close over](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-21.html#%_sec_3.2) the accumulator variable:

```
(define accumulate
  (let ((acc 0))
    (λ (new-val)
      (set! acc (+ acc new-val))
      acc)))

(accumulate 10) ;=> 10
(accumulate 4)  ;=> 14
```